# Frustration with Stack Overflow user decision to mark "Duplicate"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I posted [Two simple C# Inheritance methods result in different output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549256/two-simple-c-sharp-inheritance-methods-result-in-different-output).  User Ivan Stoev marked it "Duplicate".  He directed readers to [Difference between shadowing and overriding in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c).

Ivan's categorization of my question was wrong and prevented other viewers from answering it.  (He has since removed the tag.)  I ultimately posted my question on Microsoft's Social Forum where it was answered.  (See: [Two similar C# inheritance implementations give vastly different results](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ff15ba29-0b9d-4eb7-a696-b00d915fae66/two-similar-c-inheritance-implementations-give-vastly-different-results?forum=csharpgeneral).)

I am frustrated that I had no due process to have Ivan or another moderator reconsider the "duplicate question" categorization.

What strategies or channels are available to have a "duplicate question" categorization reconsidered?

Comment: This question will probably be flagged and closed but I agree with you. Very often my questions are inappropriately marked as duplicates of totally unrelated questions and I find it incredibly frustrating as well.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but when I read your question and then the supposed duplicate, I also think to myself "yes, this question is a duplicate". Maybe not an exact duplicate, but I'd expect the answer to that question to also answer your question.

Comment: A) dupe doesnt mean "same question",but "you will find your answer there" (it may require some tweaking on your part). B) if Ivan is a gold badge holder and can close as a dupe single-handedly, you can @ping him in comments on your question. C) the due process is "edit". That sends your question in a review queue where people can reopen it

Comment: Oh... And your question is reopened now... Your point being? (your question likely got reopened because you edited it, which sent it to the reopen queue). You say you have no way to ask for a de-duping... But there IS such a way, and you used it. Succesfully.

Comment: *"I had no due process to have Ivan or another moderator reconsider the "duplicate question" categorization"* - it is not clear why you thought that was the case.

Comment: Being marked duplicate of a question isn't a bad thing, and you shouldn't consider it so.  Your question, "Why does shadowing result in two different outputs?", is answered by telling you how shadowing works.  The linked duplicate sufficiently does this.  The fact that the linked duplicate also contrasts shadowing with overriding, which are similar but behave differently, does not negate this.  In fact, it may be advantageous, as you may have been interested in the benefits of polymorphism but were, as they say, *doing it wrong*.  For someone confused w/shadowing, this seems a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem not only on Stack Overflow, but also on other Stack Exchange sites. People will sometimes think that your question looks a lot like some other question, usually one that already has answers, and vote to close.

Most times the community is right, but the process in place is not perfect. Sometimes mistakes happen, like this one.

Problem is, I cannot think of any other process which would be more cost-effective, or more efficient regardless of effort cost.

The right thing to do in such cases is editing your question. It may then be reopened. Bringing up your case on Meta also helps. Most people won't even look at a question that is on hold on Stack Overflow, but on Meta a lot of people will look at your case and you may reach enough people to reopen it.

Comment: Be careful about proposing to send a question to meta. There is the meta effect: basically by sending a question in the spotlight in front of the more quality minded people of the site, it may skyrocket in score (if it was a good one) or be pushed to oblivion (if it wasnt)